# PHP form: Success email with only filled fields

Tags: php, forms

Been struggling with this for some time now. Basically I have 6 fields, name, email, phone, location, date and budget. Name and email are the only required fields. When I get the email I see rest of the fields as well. Is it possible to receive only fields that have been filled?

Here's the code;

```
<?php
// get posted data into local variables
$EmailFrom = "email@email.com";
$EmailTo = "email@email.com";
$Subject = "My form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Phone']));

$Location = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Location'])); 
$Date = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Date']));
$Budget = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Budget'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=#\">";
  exit;
}

$userip = ($_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Location: "; $Body .= $Location; $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Date: "; $Body .= $Date; $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Budget: "; $Body .= $Budget; $Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Name: "; $Body .= $Name; $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: "; $Body .= $Email; $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: "; $Body .= $Phone; $Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "User's IP: ". $userip;

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=#\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=#\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: When `<form>` submits all fields within it will be included in the `$_POST`, better yet use `empty()` to determine if field is filled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [empty](http://php.net/empty) to check if a value was posted or not:

```
$Phone = !empty($_POST['Phone']) ? trim(stripslashes($_POST['Phone'])) : false;
```

Then later `$Phone` will be false if it wasn't filled in and you can do this:

```
if($Phone)
    $Body .= "Phone: "; $Body .= $Phone; $Body .= "\n";
```

Comment: nice catch Paul in changing `isset()` to `empty()`

Comment: @dqlopez Thanks haha. I would not have caught it, if not for your comment on the question.

Comment: Worked great!! Thanks a lot appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a check to see if the value is there.  you could do this:

```
if (!empty($Location) { $Body .= "Location: "; $Body .= $Location; $Body .= "\n"; }
```

ect ect.  This is saying if location is not empty then do that code

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, just add a check before you concat the fields to the body like:

```
if(!$Location)
{
    $Body .= "Location: "; $Body .= $Location; $Body .= "\n";
}
/*You can also use empty like: */
if(!empty($Date))
{
    $Body .= "Location: "; $Body .= $Date; $Body .= "\n";
}
/*Continue here*/
```

Comment: No need for the $Location != "" even though it works.  If ($Location) does not having anything it will return false.  If it does it would turn true

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_POST['phone'] && !empty($_POST['phone']){
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    //add $phone to email body
}
```

Comment: why not just add to email in the first check? instead of setting an extra $has_phone variable? and doing an extra check?