# PHP Email with filled in forms only

Tags: php, email

Been struggling very much with only sending the fields that people fill in. It is a simple order form with text fields. But I want it so that only those fields that are field in get sent to my alert email. I tried the codes on the topic ["PHP form: Success email with only filled fields"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941833/php-form-success-email-with-only-filled-fields) but  my php script crashes when I do. Here is my code before I tried any modifying. This email fine only that it includes all fields I only want the one filled in. Please help I am a total noob in php. All help appreciated.

```
<?
$silver_name_badges = !empty($_POST['silver_name_badges']) ? ($_POST['silver_name_badges'])) : false;
$silver_name_badges = $_POST['silver_name_badges'];
$coffee_mug = $_POST['coffee_mug'];
$plastic_bag = $_POST['plastic_bag'];
$paper_bag = $_POST['paper_bag'];
$candy = $_POST['candy'];
$moist_towlette = $_POST['moist_towlette'];
$notepad_and_pen = $_POST['notepad_and_pen'];
$tuck_box = $_POST['tuck_box'];
$red_tie = $_POST['red_tie'];
$cap = $_POST['cap'];
$name = $_POST['Attention_To'];
$red_lanyard = $_POST['red_lanyard'];
$white_lanyard = $_POST['white_lanyard'];
$green_lanyard = $_POST['green_lanyard'];
$black_lanyard = $_POST['black_lanyard'];
$LC2415 = $_POST['LC2415'];
$FOM_2NTRI = $_POST['FOM_2NTRI'];
$ASTRO_165WMT = $_POST['ASTRO_165WMT'];
$FOL_AJ3015 = $_POST['FOL_AJ3015'];
$ACIES_NT = $_POST['ACIES_NT'];



// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.ama-japan.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'ravila@ama.com');

// Set parameters of the email
$to = "joe@ama.com";
$subject = "Ama Promo Items Ordered";
$from = " jurt@ama.com";
$headers = "From: $from";


$message = "";
$message .= "Order has been placed. Attn to: $name .\n
Items:\n";

if($Phone)
    $Body .= "Phone: "; $Body .= $Phone; $Body .= "\n";

$message .="
Silver Name Badges: $silver_name_badges\n
Coffee Mug: $coffee_mug\n
Plastic Literature Bag: $plastic_bag\n
Amada Bag: $paper_bag\n
Candy: $candy\n
Notepad & Pen: $notepad_and_pen\n
Tuck Box: $tuck_box\n
Amada Tie: $red_tie\n
Candy: $candy\n
Moist Towlette: $moist_towlette\n
Cap: $cap\n
Lanyard: 
         Red - $red_lanyard
         White - $white_lanyard
         Green - $green_lanyard
         Black - $black_lanyard\n

Rock Glass: 
            LC2415 - $LC2415
            FOM 2NTRI - $FOM_2NTRI
            ASTRO 165WMT - $ASTRO_165WMT
            FOL AJ3015 - $FOL_AJ3015
            ACIES NT - $ACIES_NT";






// Mail function that sends the email.
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  header('Location: thank-you.html');
?>
```

Comment: can you upload the error description you are getting on the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors might be related to unset POST variables.

How about a loop? It will only use what is sent over.

```
$message = "";
$message .= "Order has been placed. Attn to: $name .\n
Items:\n";

foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue){
    if (!empty($fieldValue))
        $message .= "   ". str_replace('_',' ',$fieldName) .": $fieldValue\n";
}
```

Comment: Order has been placed. Attn to: Joe Blow .

Items:
   silver_name_badges: 234
   plastic_bag: 45
   LC2415: 400
   Attention_To: Joe Blow

Comment: I assume you mean in the post variable names? so I plugged in the replace method.  `". str_replace('_',' ',$fieldName) ."`

Answer (score 0):

OK I added this and worked great. How the email comes back with the field name with underscores. How to send without underscores?:

```
<?php
//$silver_name_badges = !empty($_POST['silver_name_badges']) ? ($_POST['silver_name_badges'])) : false;
$SilverNameBadges = $_POST['Silver Name Badges'];
$CoffeeMug = $_POST['coffee_mug'];
$PlasticLiteratureBag = $_POST['plastic_bag'];
$paper_bag = $_POST['paper_bag'];
$candy = $_POST['candy'];
$moist_towlette = $_POST['moist_towlette'];
$notepad_and_pen = $_POST['notepad_and_pen'];
$tuck_box = $_POST['tuck_box'];
$red_tie = $_POST['red_tie'];
$cap = $_POST['cap'];
$name = $_POST['Attention_To'];
$red_lanyard = $_POST['red_lanyard'];
$white_lanyard = $_POST['white_lanyard'];
$green_lanyard = $_POST['green_lanyard'];
$black_lanyard = $_POST['black_lanyard'];
$LC2415 = $_POST['LC2415'];
$FOM_2NTRI = $_POST['FOM_2NTRI'];
$ASTRO_165WMT = $_POST['ASTRO_165WMT'];
$FOL_AJ3015 = $_POST['FOL_AJ3015'];
$ACIES_NT = $_POST['ACIES_NT'];



// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.amada-america.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'ravila@amada.com');

// Set parameters of the email
$to = "ravila@amada.com";
$subject = "Amada Promo Items Ordered";
$from = " nostrowski@amada.com";
$headers = "From: $from";


$message = "";
$message .= "Order has been placed. Attn to: $name .\n
Items:\n";
foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue){
    if (!empty($fieldValue))
        $message .= "   $fieldName: $fieldValue\n";
}






// Mail function that sends the email.
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  header('Location: thank-you.html');
?>
```